# Django authenticate always returns None no matter what

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to add registration/login/logout functionality. The user registration appears to be working fine, as the created user shows up in Django admin and appears in the database. However, whenever I try to implement the login functionality, it never works. I think I've narrowed down the problem to `authenticate()`.

I have tried everything, and no matter what I do, the `authenticate()` function always returns `None`. The usernames and passwords I give are clearly being stored, and yet it doesn't seem to be getting the password correctly, since printing out `raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')` in the `login_user` view gives `None`.

How can I get the login functionality to work?

In **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register_user, name='register'),
    path('login', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

In **views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            print(f'User is: {user}')
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            print(f'User is: {user}')
            print(f'username is: {username}')
            print(f'password is: {raw_password}')
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    print(f'You are now logged in as {username}')
                    messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                    return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request = request,
                    template_name = "login.html",
                    context={"form":form})

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

In **register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In **login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Log in</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `register_user` and `logout_user` views seem to be working fine. In the `register_user` view, I made it so it automatically logs the user after registration. Oddly, logging in works in this scenario. However, logging in doesn't work for the `login_user` view, for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')` here you must get `password` itself not `password1`.